# Conditional line break in ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list of li elements in an ul tag. I want to display the last two in a new line, if the screen width is smaller than 625px. The following code works perfectly well:

```html
<style>
    .NewLine { display: none; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 625px) { .NewLine { display: block; }}
    li { float: left; }
    ul { list-style: none; }
</style>

<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <p class="NewLine"></p>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

But it fails the check on https://validator.w3.org/nu because p isn't allowed to be nested with ul. What other simple, working and valid solutions are possible?

Comment: Do it with ```<li></li>``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element to create a new line between `<li>` without the need of creating HTML by setting it `display: block`

```css
li {
  display: inline;
}


/* change media query value for snippet */

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  li:nth-last-of-type(2)::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    /* demo */
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

---

#### UPDATE

Since you update your question with the rest of your CSS (which means you are using `float: left` in `<li>`. You can set `clear: left` or `clear: both` on that element instead

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}

li {
  float: left;
}


/* change media query value for snippet */

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  li:nth-last-of-type(2) {
    clear: left; /* both */
    /* demo */
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like your first approach, because with the height statement I can adjust the line spacing.

Answer (score 4):

How about wrapping it in `<li>`? That is probably what @Dialex is suggesting...

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li><p class="NewLine"></p></li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Exactly, and you don't even need to have the paragraph. Just add the class to the ```<li>```

Comment: Does not work without the paragraph, unless you define the `<li>` height manually in CSS.

Comment: li with a classed p doesn't work, neither with an nbsp; inside, see https://jsfiddle.net/mcdk0w3z/9/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using float, simply clear the float after the second element and you don't need extra element or *hack*.

```css
li {
  float: left;
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
@media  (max-width: 1200px) {
  li:nth-child(3) {
    clear:left;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
</ul>
```